# Numpy, change max value in each row to 1 without changing others

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to change max value of each rows to 1 and leave others.

Each values is between 0 to 1.

I want to change this

```py
>>> a = np.array([[0.5, 0.2, 0.1], 
...               [0.6, 0.3, 0.8], 
...               [0.3, 0.4, 0.2]])
```

into this

```py
>>> new_a = np.array([[1, 0.2, 0.1],
...                   [0.6, 0.3, 1],
...                   [0.3, 1, 0.2]])
```

Is there any good solution for this problem using np.where maybe? (without using for loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.argmax` and slice assignment:

```
>>> a[np.arange(len(a)), np.argmax(a, axis=1)] = 1
>>> a
array([[1. , 0.2, 0.1],
       [1. , 0.3, 0.6],
       [1. , 0.3, 0.2]])
>>>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but something is wrong. I tried this with `a = np.array([[0.5, 0.2, 0.1], [0.8, 0.3, 0.6], [0.4, 0.3, 0.7]])` 
and the result was 
`array([[1. , 0.2, 1. ], [1. , 0.3, 1. ], [1. , 0.3, 1. ]])` which should be `array([[1., 0.2, 0.1], [1., 0.3, 0.6], [0.4, 0.3, 1.]])`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JeightAn a slight note: this answer is more suitable in your case. ie: scenarios like _find elements that satisfy "condition", if true, set to "this"_. `numpy.where` is better when you need to _find elements that satisfy "condition", if true, set to "this", **else**, set to "that"_

Comment: @JeightAn Great!

Answer (score 3):

the question differes from desired output.
the author says he wants to replace max value and leave others but actualy he replaces max value and some others.

this is the solution for replacing max value only.

```
np.where(arr == np.amax(arr), 1, arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

U12-Forward's answer does it perfectly. Here is another answer using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```py
np.where(a[0]==a.max(1), 1, a)
# `a[0]==a.max(1)` -> ​for each row, find element that is equal to max element in that row
# `1` -> set it to `1`
# `a` -> others remain the same
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more detailed step by step process that gives us the desired output:

```
# input array
a = np.array([[0.5, 0.8, 0.1],
              [0.8, 0.9, 0.6],
               [0.4, 0.3, 12]])

# finding the max element for each row
# axis=1 is given because we want to find the max for each row
max_elements = np.amax(a, axis=1)

# this changes the shape of max_elements array so that it matches with input array(a)
# this shape change is done so that we can compare directly
max_elements = max_elements[:, None]

# this code is checking the main condition
# if the value in a row matches with the max element of that row, change it to 1
# else keep it the same
new_arr = np.where(a == max_elements, 1, a)

print(new_arr)
```

Comment: @JeightAn This answer requires lots of executions and it's slow and inefficient, why is this correct? Why not check the most upvoted answers here? Like mine... Or darkman's answer.

Comment: Mine is in one line so is @darkman's answer.

Comment: @U12-Forward I'm sorry. I changed my choice.

Comment: @JeightAn Yeah, I am just trying to feed you the fastest and most efficient code for future use, in cases that you use large datasets, mine would make your code faster.

Comment: @U12-Forward Thank you for your kind explanation.

Comment: @JeightAn Feel free to vote up all of these answers as well :)

Answer (score 1):

U12-Forward's and AcaNg's answers are perfect. Here's another way to do it usng `numpy.where`

```py
new_a = np.where(a==[[i] for i in np.amax(a,axis=1)],1,a)
```